# Стикеры телеграм на кнопках бота

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

Всем привет. Пишу своего бота телеграм на Laravel. Задался вопросом - как можно добавить свой стикер на кнопку меню? Стикер создал, есть его ID но нет unicode. Со стандартными эмодзи все понятно, есть таблицы с кодами, а вот что делать со своими?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вопрос решился. невозможно добавить на кнопку))